# foreach loop syntax for map in Apex

Tags: apex, map, loop

want the foreach loop syntax for accessing map value, like what we do for array or list

```
for(OBJ o[SELECT Id,B FROM OBJ]){
     m1.put(o.Id, o.B); 
}
```

please provide technical details

Comment: If you google search iterate map/for loop map apex, you will find a lot of information out there. This blog is a really handy reference http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/01/06/fun-with-salesforce-collections/

Answer (score 4):

```
Map<Id, OBJ> map = new Map<Id, OBJ>([SELECT Id, B FROM OBJ]); 

for(OBJ o : map.values()) { 
    System.debug(o.B); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the map keyset then grab the value using each key.

```
for (Id key : m1.keySet()) {

    OBJ o = m1.get(key);

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is SF workbook for all the For Loops:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for.htm